# Playwright: Element is not visible, unable to type on textBox

Tags: javascript, authentication, playwright

[playwright message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijGaM.jpg)Im trying to perform a login but the textbox and buttons are hidden.

when trying with .type the test passes in green but does not write anything. When using .fill i got the message on the attached image.

How can I interact with elements in that page? how do I make it visible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not much context is given, but I assume you could fill it with

```
await login.click().fill('caca')
```

It's also usually better to use the `data-testid` instead of label.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, but if I just type that line it crashes. Im sorry I dunno how to add more context, it is basically what we can see in the image, the locator gets resoved so I assume it gets found and then when I try to fill it out it waits for it to be visible etc.

Comment: When I try to click the button it says the same, it can locate it but its not visible to interact with it, I dunno how to solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
await page.locator('#email').fill('caca');
```

or

```
await page.locator("[id='email']").fill('caca');
```

or maybe:

```
await page.locator('#email').first().fill('caca');
```

**PS:** You can also use codegen and let playwright generate your code for you. More infos here: https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen